# Do we put a dash or a slash to separate X and Y in X Y crossover?

Tags: grammar

For example, when we use the expression "Star Wars Marvel crossover", do we use a slash (/) or a dash (-) to separate Star Wars and Marvel? What's the proper way of doing this, or the most popular if both are valid?

Here are some examples:

> This Star Wars-Marvel crossover is the bomb.
>
> This Star Wars/Marvel crossover is the bomb.

Comment: When it's connecting two fictional characters in a relationship it's actually called "slash fiction" https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SlashFic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either.  Printed publications tend to prefer hyphen **Star Wars-Marvel** and informal writing would often prefer slash **Star Wars/Marvel**.

The UK press has a number of articles recently about **the slashie** -- a person with multiple jobs such as "rapper/singer/actor/director" [Evening Standard](https://www.standard.co.uk/lifestyle/esmagazine/meet-the-slashies-the-savvy-londoners-holding-down-more-than-one-job-8113327.html) [Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/money/shortcuts/2019/apr/23/rise-slashie-glamorous-new-work-or-ultimate-grind)